# Undesirable buffering using okhttp client

Tags: okhttp

I am stuck in such a scenario:

> Client send a http POST request to server (header size: about 1000B, body size: 500B).
>
> I captured the packet using tcpdump in the server side(I can't make contact with my user who is the client side)
>
> The server got the first 1360B(due to the MTU) quickly.
>
> But after a long time(about 30s), the server got the remain 140B.
>
> And afterwards, the server got a FIN from the client immediately.
>
> (okhttp version: 2.6.3)

Anyone share the same experience ? Or could you give me some advice?

Comment: Seems like an environment issue. Can you reproduce this in isolation? Here's a good place to start: https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/981fcae102f513eb13ed

Comment: @JesseWilson Thanks for your reply. After tracking the network packet, we found that it's not a issue of okhttp. It occurs due to the poor network status. The lossing packet contributed to it. Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1):

After tracking the network packet, we found that it's not a issue of okhttp. It occurs due to the poor network status. The lossing packet contributed to it.